# JQuery and Rails...submitting with AJAX vs. HTML headers

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-events

This one is a little unique...

I have a series of checkbox images, that when they are clicked, the form submits...using the following Javascript:

```
$('#pin_rose').simpleImageCheck({
  image: '/images/rose.png',
  imageChecked: '/images/one.png'
   })
  .change(function() {
    var c = 'checked';
    if (!$('#pin_rose').is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }
    $(this).closest('form').submit();

});
```

However, I'd like the form to submit using ajax within the rails 3 environment, so that the page doesn't reload...

In my _edit.html partial, I have the following:

```
<%= form_for([@posts, @pin], :html => {:multipart => true}, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

In my pins_controller.rb controller I have:

```
def update
...
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.update_attributes(params[:pin])
        format.html { redirect_to @post }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { redirect_to '/static_pages/login' }
        format.js
      end
...
end
```

Then in my update.js.erb I have

```
$("#new_pins").append("<h1>new pin added</h1>")
```

The issue is that when I click the image, the form submits, and data is added, but it redirects, rather than using ajax.

Is there a way to make rails override the `$(this).closest('form').submit();` Javascript call so that it is not submitted as html?

I know I could do a standard ajax call in Javascript, but would prefer not to, as I need to pull objects in the future (the "new pin added" is just for now).

**UPDATE:** 
Ran rake routes...

```
           users POST /users(.:format)                           users#create
        new_user GET  /users/new(.:format)                       users#new
            user GET  /users/:id(.:format)                       users#show
       post_pins POST /posts/:post_id/pins(.:format)             pins#create
    new_post_pin GET  /posts/:post_id/pins/new(.:format)         pins#new
   edit_post_pin GET  /posts/:post_id/pins/:id/edit(.:format)    pins#edit
        post_pin PUT  /posts/:post_id/pins/:id(.:format)         pins#update
           posts POST /posts(.:format)                           posts#create
        new_post GET  /posts/new(.:format)                       posts#new
       edit_post GET  /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                  posts#edit
            post GET  /posts/:id(.:format)                       posts#show
                 PUT  /posts/:id(.:format)                       posts#update
           login      /login(.:format)                           static_pages#login
           about      /about(.:format)                           static_pages#about
                      /posts(.:format)                           posts#new
```

SECOND UPDATE

The main issue is that `$('#myform').submit();` is submitting as html.  Is there a way to change this to so that it goes to format.js instead?  I've also tried this to no avail:

```
<%= f.check_box :rose, :onchange => '$(this.form).submit();' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would explicitly name the form, i.e.:

```
<%= form_for([@posts, @pin], 
   :remote => true, 
   :html => {:multipart => true, :id=>'myform'} ) do |f| %>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

Comment: Just tried it and while the data gets inserted into the db, the page still redirects back to itself rather than follow the update.js.erb command.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: if i change the redirect_to object, then the page will redirect wherever I ask...but the format.js seems to be ignored.  I can't figure out why

Comment: one more thing...if I delete all javascript, and use a regular submit form, then it works...so it seems to be related to the "onchange" event...if change the checkbox to <%= f.check_box :rose, :onchange => 'this.form.submit()' %> then I get the same redirect issue.  Is there a way to make the onchange event pass through in js?

Comment: Run 'rake routes' and post results to an edit of your original question, i.e. 'UPDATE : I ran rakes routes and.....'

Comment: I think you are hitting your create action,  copy the respond_to block to your create action.